# Add one day to every date in a days vector

Tags: r, date

I have a vector of dates called KeyDates containing two key dates. I would like to make a new vector of dates called KeyDatesPlus containing those two key dates and the two days after, in chronological order.

```
KeyDates <- structure(c(15159,15165), class = "Date")

#KeyDates Output:
[1] "2011-07-04" "2011-07-10"

#desired output for KeyDatesPlus:
[1] "2011-07-04" "2011-07-05" "2011-07-10" "2011-07-11"
```

How could I achieve that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort(c(KeyDates, KeyDates + 1))
[1] "2011-07-04" "2011-07-05" "2011-07-10" "2011-07-11"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
structure( sapply(KeyDates, "+", (0:1)), class = "Date")
[1] "2011-07-04" "2011-07-05" "2011-07-10" "2011-07-11"
```

Or:

```
 as.Date( sapply(KeyDates, "+", (0:1)))
[1] "2011-07-04" "2011-07-05" "2011-07-10" "2011-07-11"
```

Comment: Did you try: `KeyDates + (0:1)`? Also got potentially useful results with `mapply` which is at the heart of Vectorize but it looked even hackier than my sapply approach. I was trying (unsuccessfully)  to find something that gave the cartesion product of arguments but didn't drop the class attribute.

Comment: Right. But I was trying for something that didn't require a sort. Different aesthetics I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
KeyDates <- structure(c(15159,15165), class = "Date")
KeyDates.plus <- as.Date(sapply(KeyDates, function(x) c(x, x+1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

An answer using the package `lubridate`:

```
library("lubridate")
your.vector <- c("2011-07-04", "2011-07-10")
your.vector <- parse_date_time(x = your.vector, orders = "ymd")
your.vector
# [1] "2011-07-04 UTC" "2011-07-10 UTC"

one.day <- days(x = 1)
one.day
# [1] "1d 0H 0M 0S"
your.vector + one.day
# [1] "2011-07-05 UTC" "2011-07-11 UTC"

# your exact desired output (non-UTC time zone can be specified in parse_date_time):
new.vector <- sort(x = c(your.vector, your.vector + one.day))
# [1] "2011-07-04 UTC" "2011-07-05 UTC" "2011-07-10 UTC" "2011-07-11 UTC"
```

Lubridate distinguishes a "period" from a "duration."

- A period is the time on the clock (ie if daylight savings time happens, it's what the clock reads). That's what's specified here using `days()`.
- A duration is the physical time (ie if daylight savings time happens, it's how long you've actually been sitting there.) That could be specified instead using `ddays()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
KeyDates <- structure(c(15159,15165), class = "Date")
KeyDatesPlus <- KeyDates+1
KeyDatesPlus <- sort(unique(c(KeyDates, KeyDatesPlus)))
```

Comment: Lots of similar answer appeared simultaneously.  I'll leave mine up as it's the only one to include unique, which could be required if two dates in the original list are consecutive